# How to remove Triangles and Ngons

Tags: modeling, mesh, modifiers, edit-mode, vertices

I'm new to Blender and 3D modelling in general. I encountered a problem where I can't remove Tris/Ngons after using the boolean modifier (Union) to combine 2 objects to make the handle of a sword.

[this is the mesh](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QoRJh.png)

[image: And how I tried to make it into quads]

Is there a way so that all of them would become Quads?
Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Using quads not always necessary. But, anyway, here how would i do this task:
[image]